# DevOps release pipeline and new azure app service "app service doesn't exist"

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-appservice

I have a number of Azure DevOps release pipelines that each deploy code to an Azure App Service.  100% of the time, for the hour or two following the creation of the new app service, these pipelines will fail with an error " '' doesn't exist. Resource should exist before deployment".

Every. Single. Time.  We are talking two dozen app services just in production alone, and it happened to all of them.  I have to wait for this error to "pass" before the pipeline will start working.  I have a big re-deploy coming up where I have to delete/re-create a dozen or more app services (to be created under App Service Plan V3, so they must be destroyed first), and I would love to create the new versions, and deploy right away.  Instead, we are facing a couple hours of production downtime as a result of this problem.

Is there any way to "convince" Azure DevOps that the app service referenced in my release pipeline does indeed exist?  Is there a way to "refresh" the connection between DevOps and my Azure tenant?

Delete an app service, re-create it (under a new V3 app service plan), and re-deploy the release from DevOps.  I'd expect the deployment to complete like it did before.  But instead, I have to wait, and do nothing else, for an hour, maybe two, at which point the deployment will "magically" start to work.

Comment: How is the app service being created?

Comment: Through the Azure portal web UI.

Comment: This sometimes happens when the Azure App Service is on the free F1 tier.  What is the App Service Plan's current tier?

Comment: Definitely not free F1.  The plan is Premium V3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the same on azure function apps. There is a huge delay between the deployment of resources and when Azure DevOps service connection starts to see the deployed resource. I use the following workaround:

1. Create steps for arm deployment and build result deployment in the same release stage and through the same service connection.
2. In this case in this one common session, the service connection passes the build result to the newly created azure resource.

In other cases, we should wait an hour or more.

To create your apps as a IaC, you may use the following:

1. Bicep: [Create App Service app using Bicep](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/provision-resource-bicep)
2. ARM Template: [Quickstart: Create App Service app using an ARM template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-arm-template?pivots=platform-linux)

Then deploy your arm or bicep through the release pipeline... as an example the yaml view for function apps:

```
steps:
- task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
  displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resource Group scope'
  inputs:
    azureResourceManagerConnection: 'Dev_Env_Deployment'
    subscriptionId: 'SubscriptionId'
    resourceGroupName: 'RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME'
    location: 'West Europe'
    csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_drop_folder/arm/function-template.json'
    csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_drop_folder/arm/function-template-parameters-dev.json'
    overrideParameters: '-functionapp_name "$(FUNCTION_NAME)"
- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy: $(FUNCTION_NAME)'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'Dev_Env_Deployment'
    appType: functionApp
    appName: '$(FUNCTION_NAME)'
    package: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_drop_folder/drop'
```

Comment: Forgive me, I'm not as familiar with ARM Templates, but will the added steps you're suggesting create the app service during execution of the release pipeline?